# Validating Zip Code for specific location in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, zipcode

I'm new to this javascript thing and I'm trying to validate a zip code to a specific city/county. When I enter a correct zip, I still get a message "NM Zip only, please". What am I doing wrong here? I'm at lost. Thank you for your help.

```js
< script language = "javascript" >

  // validates that the field value string has one or more characters in it
  function isNotEmpty(elem) {
    var str = elem.value;
    var re = /.+/;
    if (str.match(re)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("Please fill in all required fields.");
      return false;
    }
  }

//Function toggleMailAddress

function toggleMailAddress() {
  if (document.selfreg.addressToggle.checked) {
    document.selfreg.street2.value = document.selfreg.street.value;
    document.selfreg.city2.value = document.selfreg.city.value;
    document.selfreg.state2.value = document.selfreg.state.value;
    document.selfreg.postalcode2.value = document.selfreg.postalcode.value;
  } else {
    document.selfreg.stre_haddress2.value = "";
    document.selfreg.city_haddress2.value = "";
    document.selfreg.stat_haddress2.value = "";
    document.selfreg.post_haddress2.value = "";
  }
}

function blockEnter(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
  var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode :
    ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
  if (charCode == 13 || charCode == 3) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

// telephone number test
function isTelephoneNumber(elem) {
    var str = elem.value;
    var re = /^\d{3}[-. ]\d{3}[-. ]\d{4}/;
    if (!str.match(re)) {
      alert("Please enter your complete telephone number, with area code.  You may use hyphens, periods, or spaces as separators, and you may include an extension.");
      setTimeout("focusElement('" + elem.form.name + "', '" + elem.name + "')", 0);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // ZIP Code test

function isNMZipCode(elem) {
    var str = elem.value;
    var re = /^(87059,87101,87102,87103,87104,87105,87106,87107,87108,87109,87110,87111,87112,87113,87114,87115,87116,87117,87119,87120,87121,87122,87123,87124,87125,87131,87144,87151,87153,87154,87158,87165,87174,87176,87181,87184,87185,87187,87190,87191,87192,87193,87194,87195,87196,87197,87198,87199)$/;
    str = str.toString();
    if (str.match(re)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("NM ZIP Codes only, please.");
      setTimeout("focusElement('" + elem.form.name + "', '" + elem.name + "')", 0);
      return false;
    }
  }
  // birth date test

function isBirthDate(elem) {
    var str = elem.value;
    var re = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([0-9][0-9])$/;
    if (!str.match(re)) {
      alert("Please check your birthdate.\nEnter the date using only six digits (mmddyy).\nUse leading zeros if necessary (for instance, 010190 for January 1, 1990).\nIf you were born before 1920, enter 010120.");
      setTimeout("focusElement('" + elem.form.name + "', '" + elem.name + "')", 0);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // email address test

function isEmail(elem) {
  if (!elem.value) { // field may be empty
    return true;
  } else { // if not empty, test for at sign and period
    var str = elem.value;
    var re = /^.+@.+\..+$/;
    if (!str.match(re)) {
      alert("That doesn't look like a valid email address. Please be sure you have a @ and a period.");
      setTimeout("focusElement('" + elem.form.name + "', '" + elem.name + "')", 0);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

// return focus to invalid entries
function focusElement(formName, elemName) {
  var elem = document.forms[formName].elements[elemName];
  elem.focus();
  elem.select();
}

// batch validation
function validateForm(form) {
  if (isNotEmpty(form.nlast)) {
    if (isNotEmpty(form.nfirst)) {
      if (isNotEmpty(form.stre_aaddress)) {
        if (isNotEmpty(form.city_aaddress)) {
          if (isNotEmpty(form.post_aaddress)) {
            if (isNotEmpty(form.stre_haddress2)) {
              if (isNotEmpty(form.city_haddress2)) {
                if (isNotEmpty(form.stat_haddress2)) {
                  if (isNotEmpty(form.post_haddress2)) {
                    if (isNotEmpty(form.tphone1)) {
                      if (isTelephoneNumber(form.tphone1)) {
                        if (isNotEmpty(form.F051birthdate)) {
                          if (isBirthDate(form.F051birthdate)) {
                            if (isNMZipCode(form.post_haddress2)) {
                              if (isEmail(form.zemailaddr)) {
                                form.nlast.value = form.nlast.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.nmiddle.value = form.nmiddle.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.nfirst.value = form.nfirst.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.stre_aaddress.value = form.stre_aaddress.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.city_aaddress.value = form.city_aaddress.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.stat_aaddress.value = form.stat_aaddress.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.stre_haddress2.value = form.stre_haddress2.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.city_haddress2.value = form.city_haddress2.value.toUpperCase();
                                form.ddepartment.value = form.ddepartment.value.toUpperCase();
                                return true;
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

< /script>

<script language="JavaScript">
 function toggleMailAddress() {
  if (document.selfreg.addressToggle.checked) {
  document.selfreg.stre_haddress2.value = document.selfreg.stre_aaddress.value;
  document.selfreg.city_haddress2.value = document.selfreg.city_aaddress.value;
  document.selfreg.stat_haddress2.value = document.selfreg.stat_aaddress.value;
  document.selfreg.post_haddress2.value = document.selfreg.post_aaddress.value;
 }
else {
  document.selfreg.stre_haddress2.value = "";
  document.selfreg.city_haddress2.value = "";
  document.selfreg.stat_haddress2.value = "";
  document.selfreg.post_haddress2.value = "";
 }
}
 function blockEnter(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
  var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode :
   ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
  if (charCode == 13 || charCode == 3) {
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }
/ / This
function is used to change lower to upper
case for the Input text

function cUpper(cObj) {
  cObj.value = cObj.value.toUpperCase();
}

< /script>
```

```html
<div class="pageContentInner">
  <h1 class="pageHeader">Form</h1>
  <div id="accessibleForm" class="form1Part">
    <form method="post" name="selfreg" class="unpadded" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="TemplateName" value="bonline">



      <fieldset>
        <legend>Please enter the following information: (<span class="formRequired">*</span> means required field)</legend>

        <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>
              <table width="90%" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="formLabel"><span class="formRequired">*</span>First Name:</span>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="nfirst" value="" size="20" maxlength="40" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)">
&nbsp;use tab key or mouse to move between boxes
</span>

                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Middle Name or Initial:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="nmiddle" value="" size="10" maxlength="40" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Last Name:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="nlast" value="" size="40" maxlength="60" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Mailing Street Address or PO Box:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="stre_aaddress" value="" size="32" maxlength="128" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)">
&nbsp;example: 123 Main St, or PO Box 123</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Mailing City:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="city_aaddress" value="" size="20" maxlength="48" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Mailing State:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    NM
                    <input type="hidden" name="stat_aaddress" value="NM">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!--<tr>
<td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Mailing State:</td>
<td colspan="2">
<span class="formHelpNote"><input name="stat_aaddress" value="NM" size="10" maxlength="2" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>
</td>
</tr>-->
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Mailing Zip Code:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="post_aaddress" value="" size="12" maxlength="5" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)">
&nbsp;must be within Albuquerque/Bernalillo County</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addressToggle" id="addressToggle" onchange="toggleMailAddress()" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)">My mailing address is the same as my residence address.
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">Residence address:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Residence Street Address (no PO Boxes, please):</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="stre_haddress2" value="" size="32" maxlength="128" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)">
&nbsp;example: 123 Main St</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Residence City:</td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="city_haddress2" value="" size="20" maxlength="48" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <td>Residence State:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="stat_haddress2" value="NM" size="10" maxlength="2" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)" onkeyup="return cUpper(this)"></span>

                  <!--<tr>
<td>Residence State:</td>
<td colspan="2">
CA
<input type="hidden" name="stat_haddress2" value="NM">
</td>
</tr>-->
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      </span>Residence Zip Code:</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="post_haddress2" value="" size="12" maxlength="5" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)"></span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="tphone1" value="" size="16" maxlength="30" onchange="isTelephoneNumber(this)" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)">
&nbsp;example: 415-555-5555</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Alternate Phone Number:</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="pphone2" value="" size="16" maxlength="30" onchange="isTelephoneNumber(this)" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)">
&nbsp;example: 415-555-5555</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="formRequired">*</span>Birthdate:</td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                      <span class="formHelpNote"><input name="F051birthdate" value="" size="8" maxlength="6" onchange="isBirthDate(this)" onkeydown="return blockEnter(event)">
&nbsp;mmddyy; example: 053185 for May 31, 1985</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

              </table>
              <br />After clicking the Submit button, please wait for the confirmation screen.
              <br />
              <br />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" border="0" class="button">
              <br />
              <br />
    </form>
    <!--startover-->
    <!--End of main page content-->
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <!--accessibleForm -->
</div>
<!-- pageContentInner -->
<!--End the main content table-->

<br />
</div>
<!-- pageContent  -->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: the regexp does not test what you think, you need groups and "|" separations i think

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but note that your `validateForm` function doesn't need all those nested `if` statements. It's really just `if(isNotEmpty(form.nlast) && isNotEmpty(form.nfirst) && isNotEmpty(form.stre_aaddress)...` etc.

Comment: What @dandavis is saying is that your regex should actually look like this: `/^(87059|87101|87102|87103 ... )$/`.

Comment: @dandavis (and @Simon) is correct and that solves your problem. If you are looking for a way to validate more than just a zipcode, and more than just one state, take a look at the [SmartyStreets API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/address) for real-time address (or just zipcode) validation.